# Getting Following Error When i am trying to generate .apk file

Tags: sencha-touch-2.1

when i am trying to generate .apk file from SenchaTouch App with command "sencha app build native", i got the following error, Can any one please tell me the solution

```
C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch>sencha app build native
Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45
[INF]
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF]
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-sencha-command:
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] app-build-impl:
[INF]
[INF] -before-init-local:
[INF]
[INF] -init-local:
[INF]
[INF] -after-init-local:
[INF]
[INF] init-local:
[INF]
[INF] find-cmd-in-path:
[INF]
[INF] find-cmd-in-environment:
[INF]
[INF] find-cmd-in-shell:
[INF]
[INF] init-cmd:
[INF]      [echo] Using Sencha Cmd from C:\Users\Zenith\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.1.45
for C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\build.xml
[INF]
[INF] -before-init:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF] Initializing Sencha Cmd ant environment
[INF] Adding antlib taskdef for com/sencha/command/compass/ant/antlib.xml
[INF]
[INF] -after-init:
[INF]
[INF] -before-init-defaults:
[INF]
[INF] -init-defaults:
[INF]
[INF] -after-init-defaults:
[INF]
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] -before-build:
[INF]
[INF] refresh:
[INF]
[INF] -before-refresh:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF]
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF]
[INF] -detect-app-build-properties:
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\touch
\src
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\app.j
s
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\app
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\build
\temp\native\TouchEx1\sencha-compiler\app
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\build
\temp\native\TouchEx1\sencha-compiler\app
[INF] Concatenating output to file C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch/
build/temp/native/TouchEx1/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] Adding external reference : @full-page => @overrides
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\build
\temp\native\TouchEx1\sencha-compiler\cmd-packages.js
[INF] Adding external reference : Ext.util.Observable => C:\Users\Zenith\Webstor
mProjects\SenchaTouch/build/temp/native/TouchEx1/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js

[INF]
[INF] -refresh-app:
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\Sen
chaTouch/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\Sen
chaTouch/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\Sen
chaTouch/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\Sen
chaTouch/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\Sen
chaTouch/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending content to C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch/bootstra
p.json
[INF]
[INF] -refresh:
[INF]
[INF] -after-refresh:
[INF]
[INF] resolve:
[INF]
[INF] js:
[INF]
[INF] -before-js:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF]
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF]
[INF] -detect-app-build-properties:
[INF]
[INF] -compile-js:
[INF] Compressing data with YuiJavascriptCompressor
[INF] Concatenating output to file C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch/
build/native/TouchEx1/app.js
[INF]
[INF] -js:
[INF]
[INF] -after-js:
[INF]
[INF] resources:
[INF]
[INF] -before-resources:
[INF]
[INF] -before-inherit-resources:
[INF]
[INF] -before-copy-resources:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF]
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF]
[INF] -resources:
[INF] merging resources into C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\build\
native\TouchEx1\resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\build
\native\TouchEx1\resources
[INF] merging resources into C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\build\
native\TouchEx1
[INF] merged 0 resources into C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\build
\native\TouchEx1
[INF]
[INF] -after-copy-resources:
[INF]
[INF] -after-inherit-resources:
[INF]
[INF] -after-resources:
[INF]
[INF] sass:
[INF]
[INF] -before-sass:
[INF]
[INF] -compass-compile-theme-package:
[INF]
[INF] -compass-compile-theme-folders:
[INF]
[INF] -compass-compile-sass-dir:
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
identical ../css/app.css
[INF]
[INF] -compass-compile:
[INF]
[INF] -sass:
[INF]
[INF] -after-sass:
[INF]
[INF] slice:
[INF]
[INF] -before-slice:
[INF]
[INF] -slice-images:
[INF]
[INF] -slice:
[INF]
[INF] -after-slice:
[INF]
[INF] page:
[INF]
[INF] -before-page:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF]
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF]
[INF] -copy-app-resources:
[INF] Copying page resources to C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\bui
ld\native\TouchEx1
[INF] copying C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\resources\css\app.css
 to C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\build\native\TouchEx1\resources
\css\app.css
[INF]
[INF] -generate-deltas:
[INF]
[INF] -detect-app-build-properties:
[INF]
[INF] -build-standalone-json-manifest:
[INF] Writing content to C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch/build/nati
ve/TouchEx1/app.json
[INF]
[INF] -build-output-page:
[INF]
[INF] -build-output-microload-page:
[INF] Writing content to C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch/build/nati
ve/TouchEx1/microloader.js
[INF] Appending content to C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch/build/na
tive/TouchEx1/microloader.js
[INF] Building output markup to C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch/bui
ld/native/TouchEx1/index.html
[INF]    [delete] Deleting: C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\build\n
ative\TouchEx1\microloader.js
[INF]
[INF] -generate-cache-manifest:
[INF]
[INF] -page:
[INF]
[INF] -after-page:
[INF]
[INF] native-package:
[INF]
[INF] -before-native-package:
[INF]
[INF] -native-package-mobile:
[INF]      [echo] Building all specified mobile packager configs.
[INF]      [echo]
[INF]      [echo]     Processing Mobile Packager config file
[INF]      [echo]         config: C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch/p
ackager.json
[INF]      [echo]         inputPath: C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouc
h/build/native/TouchEx1
[INF]      [echo]         outputPath: C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTou
ch/build/native-package-mobile/TouchEx1/packager.json
[INF]      [echo] Running mobile packager action build on file C:\Users\Zenith\W
ebstormProjects\SenchaTouch/packager.temp.json
[ERR]
Error: Package name 'TouchEx1' contains invalid characters.
A package name must be constitued of two Java identifiers.
Each identifier allowed characters are: a-z A-Z 0-9 _
""C:/Users/Zenith/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522/sdk\tools\android"
create project --target android-8 --name TouchEx1 --activity STActivity --path "
C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch/build/native-package-mobile/TouchEx
1/packager.json\/" --package TouchEx1"
Can not open destination file for writing
Failed to copy packager library
Failed to package application
Copy operation failed src=C:\Users\Zenith\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.1.45\stbuild\st-res
/android/\nimblekit.jar dst=C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch/build/n
ative-package-mobile/TouchEx1/packager.json\\libs\nimblekit.jar

***

    **[ERR]
    **[ERR] BUILD FAILED
    [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: stbuild exited with non-zero code : 3
    [ERR]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Targ
    [ERR] et.java:413)
    [ERR]
    [ERR] Total time: 12 seconds
    [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line**:
    C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:422: The
     following error occurred while executing this line:**

***
C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:112:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:114:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:98: T
he following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Zenith\WebstormProjects\SenchaTouch\.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:7: co
m.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: stbuild exited with non-zero code : 3
```

**packager.json**

```
{
    /**
     * @cfg  applicationName
     * @required
     * This is the name of your application, which is displayed on the device when the app is installed. On IOS, this should match
     * the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
     */
    "applicationName":"TouchEx1",

    /**
     * @cfg  applicationId
     * This is the name namespace for your application. On IOS, this should match the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
     */
    "applicationId":"TouchEx1",

    /**
     * @cfg  bundleSeedId
     * A ten character string which stands before aplication ID in Apple Provisioning Portal
     */
    "bundleSeedId":"KPXFEPZ6EF",

    /**
     * @cfg  versionString
     * @required
     * This is the version of your application.
     */
    "versionString":"1.0",

/**
 * @cfg  versionCode
 * @required
 * This is the integer version code of your application, or you can refer to it as a build number. Used only for Android builds.
 */
"versionCode":"1",

/**
 * @cfg  icon
 * For iOS, please refer to their documentation about icon sizes:
 * https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html
 *
 * For Android, please refer to the Google Launcher icons guide:
 * http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html
 * iOS uses 57, 72, 114 and 144; Android uses 36, 48 and 72; if you package for Android you can ignore iOS icons and vice verca
 */
"icon": {
    "36":"resources/icons/Icon_Android36.png",
    "48":"resources/icons/Icon_Android48.png",
    "57":"resources/icons/Icon.png",
    "72":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",
    "114":"resources/icons/Icon@2x.png",
    "144":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png"
},

/**
 * @cfg  inputPath
 * @required
 * This is location of your Sencha Touch 2 application, relative to this configuration file.
 */
"inputPath":"C:/Users/Zenith/WebstormProjects/SenchaTouch",

/**
 * @cfg  outputPath
 * @required
 * This is where the built application file with be saved. Make sure that output path is not in your input path, you may get into endless recursive copying
 */
"outputPath":"C:/Users/Zenith/Desktop/APKS",

/**
 * @cfg  configuration
 * @required
 * This is configuration for your application. `Debug` should always be used unless you are submitting your app to an online
 * store - in which case `Release` should be specified.
 */
"configuration":"Debug",

/**
 * @cfg  platform
 * @required
 * This is the platform where you will be running your application. Available options are:
 *  - iOSSimulator
 *  - iOS
 *  - Android
 *  - AndroidEmulator
 */
"platform":"Android",

/**
 * @cfg  deviceType
 * @required
 * This is device type that your application will be running on.
 *
 * If you are developing for Android, this is not necessary.
 *
 * Available options are:
 *  - iPhone
 *  - iPad
 *  - Universal
 */
"deviceType":"Universal",

/**
 * @cfg  certificatePath
 * This is the location of your certificate.
 * This is required when you are developing for Android or you are developing on Windows.
 */
"certificatePath":"C:/Users/Zenith/WebstormProjects/SenchaTouch",

/**
 * @cfg  certificateAlias
 * This is the name of your certificate.
 *
 * IF you do not specify this on OSX, we will try and automatically find the certificate for you using the applicationId.
 *
 * This can be just a simple matcher. For example, if your certificate name is "iPhone Developer: Robert Dougan (ABCDEFGHIJ)", you
 * can just put "iPhone Developer".
 *
 * When using a certificatePath on Windows, you do not need to specify this.
 */
"certificateAlias":"",
/**
 * @cfg  certificatePassword
 * The password which was specified during certificate export
 */
"certificatePassword":"chanti",
/**
 * @cfg  provisionProfile
 * The path to the provision profile (APP_NAME.mobileprovision) which you can create and then download from Apple's provisioning portal
 */
"provisionProfile":"",
/**
 * @cfg  notificationConfiguration
 * Notification configuration for push notifications, can be "debug", "release" or empty if you don't use push notifications in your project.
 */
"notificationConfiguration":"",
/**
 * @cfg  sdkPath
 * This is the path to the Android SDK, if you are developing an Android application.
 */
"sdkPath":"C:/Users/Zenith/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522/sdk",

/**
 * @cfg  androidAPILevel
 * This is android API level, the version of Android SDK to use, you can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html.
 * Be sure to install corresponding platform API in android SDK manager (android_sdk/tools/android)
 */
"androidAPILevel":"8",

    /**
 * @cfg {Array[String]} permissions
 * Array of permissions that is used by an application (Android only) 
 * Full list of permissions for Android application can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES
 */
"permissions":[
        "INTERNET",
        "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
        "CAMERA",
        "VIBRATE",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "CALL_PHONE"
    ],

/**
 * @cfg {Array[String]} orientations
 * @required
 * This is orientations that this application can run.
 */
"orientations": [
    "portrait",
    "landscapeLeft",
    "landscapeRight",

        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the solution, There androidId Should be the fully qualified name, i just changed and succeeded in generating the apk file